# How to associate ip range to interface

Tags: dhcp, configuration, linux-networking

How to associate ip range to specific interface.
I have multiple vlans and till today i have worked with 1 ip range, but i need to increase ip range to second vlan.

My first few lines of config

```
   ddns-updates off;
    #ddns-update-style interim;
    ddns-update-style none;
    ignore client-updates;


    allow bootp;
    allow booting;
        shared-network siec {
                subnet 192.168.80.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
                        authoritative;
                        option routers          192.168.80.1;
                        option subnet-mask      255.255.255.0;
                        option domain-name              "aaaa.prv";
                        option domain-name-servers      85.22.22.14, 85.22.22.2;
        #               option domain-name-servers      192.168.0.1, 85.22.22.14;
        #               option domain-name-servers      192.168.0.1;
                        option netbios-name-servers     192.168.0.2;
                        default-lease-time 86400;
                        max-lease-time 172800;
                        range dynamic-bootp 192.168.80.2 192.168.80.50;
                        option ntp-servers 192.168.0.2;
        }

        host tel_testowy {
               hardware ethernet cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc;
               fixed-address 192.168.80.51;
        }

                subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.254.0 {
                        authoritative;
                        option routers          192.168.0.5;
                        option subnet-mask      255.255.254.0;
                        option domain-name              "222.prv";
                        option domain-name-servers      85.22.22.14, 85.12.22.2;
        #               option domain-name-servers      192.168.0.1, 85.14.22.14;
        #               option domain-name-servers      192.168.0.1;
                        option netbios-name-servers     192.168.0.2;
                        default-lease-time 86400;
                        max-lease-time 172800;
                        range dynamic-bootp 192.168.0.110 192.168.0.150;
                        range dynamic-bootp 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.200;
                        option ntp-servers 192.168.0.2;
}
# VMWare

host v8_backup_ip {
       hardware ethernet 00:50:56:7A:75:9C;
       fixed-address 192.168.0.158;
}
```

and my computer from vlan behind 192.168.80.0 network gets 192.168.1.115 ip from dynamic range 192.168.0.0 network.
Do you know how should i correct this config to work properly?

Comment: I forgot, i have corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DHCP will only assign IPs that match the subnet of the interface.

So if you have 192.168.0.0/24 and 192.168.123.0/24; you need two ranges setup in DHCP, one for each, and it will automatically match them appropriately.

Comment: I have sold my problem, i have made some modifications and i dont know which one made progress but who cares if it works. 
So i used groups and removed shared-network and write option broadcast domains.